# Cache mapbox Tile images

Tags: javascript, jquery, caching, mapbox

I used Mapbox on a project and now I want to improve the performance of it. Is it possible to cache the Mapbox Tile images?

When I use my Mapbox map, I see request urls that look like this:

> http://b.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/{mapId}/13/4381/2564.png

I am wondering if someone could help me to figure out how to set up my own Tile caching, so I can push it out to my customers from my own server.

Answer (score 4):

I was hoping this wasn't against mapbox's TOS too... however, it appears that it is. End-users can cache tiles, but aren't allowed to serve them to other users. Down further in their [Terms of Service](http://www.mapbox.com/tos/) it gives more details--I bolded the parts I thought most relevant:

"Maps hosted on Mapbox may be cached on end-user devices (laptops, smartphones, tablets) for offline use, however, each device must populate its cache using direct requests to Mapbox and **content from a cache may only be consumed by a single end-user**. Further redistribution from a cache is prohibited as is proxying and any other redistribution of maps served from Mapbox. **Scraping or any mass download by a single user for purposes other than offline caching on end-user devices is prohibited.**"

Answer (score 2):

This is **Not** against mapbox's TOS.

> Offline caching Devices 
>   — phones, tablets, computers — may cache an
>   unlimited amount of map imagery for offline use or to improve
>   performance. You may not proxy or redistribute cached content.

Comment: Granted but it also says can be used to improve performance, which sounds like that is the OP's reason for cacheing in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

This is against the [MapBox Terms of Service](http://www.mapbox.com/tos/) and would result in your account being terminated.